# Array assignment with reference types?

Tags: c#, arrays, ado.net

Lets say I have some known library to load data from an .xls file and returns a DataTable populated with data from the first sheet in any excel workbook. Also a Log function that prints out messages in the absence of a working debugger.

```cs
DataTable dtFoo = null;
DataTable dtBar = null;
DataTable dtChaz = null;

String[] files = new String[]{ "file1.xls", "file2.xls", "file2.xls" };
DataTable[] dts = new DataTable[] { dtFoo, dtBar, dtChaz };

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    dts[i] = SomeLibrary.LoadFromFile(files[i]); //Returns a new DataTable
    Log((dts[i] == null) + " " + dts[i].Rows.Count)
}

Log((dts[0] == null) + " " + (dtFoo == null));
Log((dts[1] == null) + " " + (dtBar == null));
Log((dts[2] == null) + " " + (dtChaz == null));
```

`Log Output:`

```
  False 40
  False 455
  False 34
  False True
  False True
  False True
```

Clearly I'm missing something important when working with reference type variables that I haven't been able to figure out. Why are my DataTable variables still null after the loop completes?

Comment: Look into using a DataSet. The DataTable array will copy the DataTables into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
DataTable[] dts = new DataTable[] { dtFoo, dtBar, dtChaz };
```

... doesn't *alias* the variables with the array elements, as you seem to think it does. It just creates a new array, and sets the initial *values* to the values of `dtFoo`, `dtBar` and `dtChaz` respectively (all of which are null). The array and the variables are entirely separate afterwards.

If you want to set the variables later, you'll need:

```
dtFoo = dts[0];
dtBar = dts[1];
dtChaz = dts[2];
```

Of course this doesn't have to be with `DataTable`s. Simple example:

```
string x = "initial";
string[] array = new string[] { x };
array[0] = "modified";

Console.WriteLine(x); // "initial"
x = array[0];
Console.WriteLine(x); // "modified"
```

Note that this is when you change the *value of the array element*. If instead you modify the object that the value refers to, that's a different matter:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("123");
StringBuilder[] array = new StringBuilder[] { builder };
builder[0].Append("456");
Console.WriteLine(builder); // 123456
```

See my article on [reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) for more details. Basically you need to differentiate between *references* and the objects they refer to.

Comment: I think I understand. So lets say I changed my `DataTable dtFoo = null;` lines to `DataTable dtFoo = new DataTable();` & dtBar, dtChaz for all 3 DataTables. And my `SomeLibrary.LoadFromFile` function added rows to the table instead of returning a new one -- it would work?

Answer (score 2):

as suggestion you can do instead of the code you tried

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dtFoo);
ds.Tables.Add(dtBar);
ds.Tables.Add(dtChaz );
```

addd table to dataset instead of creating array of datatable

so modified code will be

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    ds.Tables.Add(SomeLibrary.LoadFromFile(files[i])); //Returns a new DataTable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the lines

```
dtFoo = dts[0];
dtBar = dts[1];
dtChaz = dts[2];
```

Before the log lines.

The init statement has no effect on the assignment statements.